# an example of supremum using relation other than <. like using divides etc??

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

i want to know some examples of supremum or infimum on a poset using relation, other than $\le$, for example using divides or mod. basiclly i want to know how to find out the supremum of a poset for an arbitary relation.

thank you

Comment: For an arbitrary partial order, we can hardly say more than: use the definition. The infimum with respect to "divides" is (of course) the gcd